# Delete data from firebase in recyclerview using childeventlistener

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to delete an image and some data from firebase and remove these from my recyclerview.

I have successfully managed to accomplish this and it's deleting the image allright, but it's not instantly deleting the image in the interface.

I have to leave the activity and return in order to view the updated view.

this is my ChildEventListener:

```
 mDBListener = mDatabaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            mUploads.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                mUploads.add(upload);

            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

what happens when i press delete:

```
@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
    final Upload selectedITem = mUploads.get(position);
    final String selectedKey =  selectedITem.getKey();
    Log.d(TAG, "SelectedKEY" + selectedKey);

    StorageReference imageref = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedITem.getImageUrl());
    imageref.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null) {

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();
                String selectedId = (String) bd.get("selectedId");

                mDatabaseRef.child(selectedId).child(selectedKey).removeValue();
                Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, "Item deleted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and the onDestroy override:

```
   @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mDatabaseRef.removeEventListener(mDBListener);
}
```

}

---

---

**UPDATED TRY FOR SOLUTION**

I tried for a solution and got a little bit closer to my goal.
Now when I delete an item in the view, and call for a Toast in my onChildRemoved, I get the toast. This is the code:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseRefff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Uid).child(selectedId).child(selectedId).child(key);


    dbEvent = mDatabaseRefff.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, "Item deleted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

so basically I did not remove the old childeventlistener (Because it worked perfectly as it was supposed to work for everything else)

And now i put this childEventlistener below the first one, only now I am listening on the same child as I am trying to remove.

Now when I delete an item from the view, I get the Toast "Item deleted".

The problem is that when I add mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

It still only shows the toast and nothing else happens...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to Override onChildRemoved, remove the item from the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the recyclerView.

> **onChildRemoved()** Listen for items being removed from a list. The DataSnapshot passed to
>   the event callback contains the data for the removed child.

```
@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //add logic to remove item from adapter
    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

    //mAdapter.remove(index);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Following the update on the question, the next thing to do is simply update the Adapter, you detect what was removed from the database through the o*nChildRemove()* and remove that from your *adapter*. Once you remove from the *adapter*, you simply call *notifyDataSetChanged()* and should work.

More info about [Firebase Listen for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events)

Comment: updated my question, and I had already tried this, no success.. Right now, when I delete an item, the toast "item deleted", appears but the item stays where it is until I go to another activity and then return.

Comment: If you move the Toast to the onChildRemoved(), do you see it being triggered?

Comment: If it doesn't get trigger, I believe it's because that childEventListener isn't listening the path you are removing the item. What is the reference that you registered the ChildEventListener?

Comment: mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Uid).child(selectedId);
Uid is the unique user that is signed in, and selectedId is the selected "button" the user has pressed when he wanted to arrive to the recyclerview layout.

Comment: Per my understanding, you are removing from:
mDatabaseRef.child(selectedId).child(selectedKey).removeValue();

And Listening for events on:
mDatabaseRef.child(Uid).child(selectedId)

If so, removing the selectedKey won't trigger any event.

Comment: That was a good comment! I have updated my question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to find a solution in the childEventListener method. So I used valueEventListener instead and solved the issue.